# Smartwatch that provides SDK for writing apps that communicate via Bluetooth or WiFi with device of choice

Tags: sdk, bluetooth, sony-smartwatch, pebble-watch

I was checking out the Pebble and Samsung Gear2 watches (and other). I could not find an explicit statement about the connectivity. Pebble has an iOS and Android SDK. What I am looking for is a smartwatch that can communicate with an device (Laptop, ARM based device or other) via Bluetooth or WiFi to establish a connection and exchange information. The initiator can be the device or the smartwatch - either choice.

I think the Samsung Gear2 can only work when an Phone/Tablet App is in Host mode and uses the Manager to upload the actual Widget on the watch?
What about an Pebble SDK for C/C++?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Partial answer: Pebble provides, roughly, four SDKs. One for Android, one for iOS, one for JavaScript that targets both Android and iOS, and a C API for writing apps on the watch itself. Using the C and JS APIs, for example, you could build an app that makes arbitrary HTTP calls to a particular devices like a laptop, but this would require a connected phone, as the watch itself has no wifi.

Comment: Pebble can be BT paired to a laptop. This is one way to install apps while developing them, for instance. Arbitrary BT communication between a laptop and a watch is not officially supported; I think you'd have to hack it in somehow. Pebble only supports one BT connection at a time.

Comment: Im interested in building a standalone app which can make use of BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices such as a bicycle speed/cadence meter or whatever device just to "connect to it" directly through bluetooth (in the example given this would connect to the speedometer and poll the speed/cadence. LEts call this example A. B example would work similary just that a device (raspberry or other) would connect to the smartwatch and expose some data to it (or push some messages with data). Is this possible (only?) through pebble? Thx In advance.

Comment: Nope, at the moment Pebble apps cannot interact with BLE devices other than the user's phone.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm looking at getting a bracelet or watch that uses BT to have it vibrate. I'd like to bypass writing an app for IOS or Android and have the app live on a windows machine.  I'd think that this should be relatively simple using bluetooth.

Comment: Pebble has announced on its Kickstarter page (https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/597507018/pebble-time-awesome-smartwatch-no-compromises/description) that it will come with a BLE API later in 2015. Stay tuned ;)